# ADB Devices not showing phone, og droid

Tags: java, android, adb

Hey Everyone,
I have had this working before, but all of the sudden it stopped working, I have reinstalled the drivers, restarted the adb server, restarted the phone and computer a few times, and it just won't work. The thing that is weird about it is that I had it working before, and it just stopped working, if I never had it working before, then I would assume I just didn't have something installed correctly, but it must be if it worked before. Any ideas for anything I can do to fix this, I am getting tired of using the crappy emulator :p

Thanks,
WWaldo

Edit: Editing the edit, because I am dumb and forgot I had the copy mode on...no new info on the issue then :(

Comment: What platform is it? Do you see anything under `adb devices` at all? Can you still see your phone in your file manager if you enable it as a disk drive?

Comment: It is running android 2.3.3, and nothing under adb devices at all, and i didn't realize that the mounting doesn't work either. Is it possible that it is an error in the rom I am running?

Comment: Not an answer but perhaps helpful, I had the same problem and resorted to using flex which has its own emulator which is fast and efficient, might be a worthwhile option. As my computer is relatively old android emulator is slow and does things like you describe often

Comment: Platform = host platform. Windows? In any case, I suspect a bad cable. I had two Micro USB cables fail on me already. These things are fragile.

Comment: I just tried another cable, still no go, guess its possible this one is busted too. Yeah, I am running windows, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

It can be many things:

- bad device drivers: try removing all usb drivers for the device and start from scratch
- bad mb drivers preventing the recognition of any usb: look into the device manager for trouble
- as EboMike said, bad cable: do you hear the sound when the device is plugged in?
- phone not in debug mode: adb requires usb debug mode. Check the phone settings
- bad ROM: you mention "the rom I am running": flash another one and check

Comment: I tried removing all of the drivers yesterday, didn't help, I will try that again though. It recognizes my USB mouse, so I am guessing the motherboard drivers are fine. I do hear the sound when I plug it in, and it is in debug mode, guess I will try reflashing cyanogen

Comment: New rom didn't work either, and neither did reinstalling the drivers

Comment: @WWaldo did you try another PC?

Comment: @Aleadam I don't have another one at my disposal sadly

Comment: @WWaldo that way you would know if it's the pc or the phone. Did you try reflashing cyanogen? Try some other (Froyo) rom for your phone. Or look into xda-developers for help in this.

Comment: @Aleadam Yeah, if I can get a hold of another computer I will have to test it then, I just tested another rom on the phone a bit ago, and nothing changed, I will check xda now

Comment: @WWaldo OK. Send me a PM there if you like. I'm not sure this is on topic here...

Comment: Okay, its definitely my computer, I just checked my dads droid running stock and it did the same thing, so...yeah, I don't what to try now though